# 3rd party integrations for reporting?

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, integration

Any recommendations on 3rd party integrations for reporting?

Use case:
Creating an actual gauged dashboard that displays open rates, unsubscribe rates, clicks, etc.  If you've used Marketo, you might know what I mean.

I need to pass data up the chain to the VP and the current reports are very readable at the high-level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without buiding something fairly customised where you stage Marketing Cloud tracking data outside of the platform and create your dashboard reporting there, you should maybe consider looking at the [Tableau add in](https://www.google.co.id/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi-jLOLqIDVAhXFrI8KHeEEBFkQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhubexchange.s1.marketingcloudapps.com%2Flisting%2Fclickmail%2Ftableau&usg=AFQjCNHfXpiPQsS0LkPu9O5CUp8imA6i2g) developed by ClickMail. I have no vested interest in these guys, but it's the only productised solution I've come across that doesn't involve pulling tracking information out of Marketing Cloud to an external data store to build reporting on.