# is there an app for marketing cloud that can be used for custom reporting?

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, salesforce1-app, app

We have some users in marketing cloud system who are not familiar with sql query and need reports / counts / numbers etc on regular basis.

As of now, I create sql queries on the basis of request since all the reports are based on the data in data extension.

Is there any app for marketing cloud that offers a GUID interface for users and can be used to pull reports out of data extensions instead of writing sql queries from scratch for each report request?

Comment: This has been addressed before. 
 https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/183524/3rd-party-integrations-for-reporting

Answer (score 0):

Since no answer (with an upvote or best answer) has been posted yet, let me point out that [DESelect](https://deselect.io?utm_source=sfse&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=sf-se-2) allows you to write SQL queries through a drag-and-drop interface. It's an app that plugs into your SFMC environment and its completely integrated.

Do note that the app approaches this (creating queries) from a targeting and segmentation point of view (at least at the moment). It's not actually a reporting tool, so you would not be able to visualize your data. But it could help you to build the queries you need (without SQL) which in turn you could use to build your report.

I'm also curious if there's other tools in the meantime that can create these kind of reports more easily inside of SFMC. I've worked with **Discover Reports**, but my experience was that they take a long time to load, and I very often experienced issues (re-)opening them (they just wouldn't load at all, some caching issue).